# Running Solidity contract results in "ENOENT: no such file or directory" error

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, enoent

I am practicing writing smart contracts in Solidity and running the code below results in
no such file or directory error.

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\kickstart\ethereum\build:Campaign.json'

This is a Kickstarter type contract with multiple participants and a manager(owner of the contract). Users are able to donate funds. The manager is the only one who is able to withdraw money, but other user`s permission is needed for that type of action.

```
 **Campaign.sol**
    pragma solidity ^0.4.20;

contract CampaignFactory {
    address[] public deployedCampaigns;


    function createCampaign(uint minimum) public {
     address newCampaign = new Campaign(minimum, msg.sender);
     deployedCampaigns.push(newCampaign);
    }

    function getDeployedCampaigns() public view returns(address []) {
        return deployedCampaigns;
    }

}
contract Campaign {
    struct Request {
        string description;
        uint value;
        address recipient;
        bool complete;
        uint approvalCount;
        mapping(address => bool) approvals;
            }

Request[] public requests;
address public manager;

uint public minimumContribution;
//address[] public approvers; mapping has a constant time lookup
mapping(address => bool) public approvers;
uint public approversCount;

modifier restricted() {
    require(msg.sender == manager);
    _;
}

constructor (uint minimum, address creator) public {
    manager = creator;
    minimumContribution = minimum;
}

function contribute() public payable {
    require(msg.value > minimumContribution);

  approvers[msg.sender] = true;  
  approversCount++;

}

function createRequest(string description, uint value, address recipient) public restricted {
    Request memory newRequest = Request({
        description: description,
        value:value,
        recipient: recipient,
        complete: false,
        approvalCount:0
    });

    requests.push(newRequest);
     }

     function approveRequest(uint index) public {
         Request storage request = requests[index];

         require (approvers [msg.sender]);
         require(!request.approvals[msg.sender]);

         request.approvals[msg.sender] = true;
         request.approvalCount++;



     }

     function finalizeRequest(uint index) public restricted {
     Request storage request = requests[index];

     require(!request.complete);
     request.complete = true;

     }
 }

**compile.js**
const path = require("path");
const solc = require("solc");
//file system on local compuiter
const fs = require("fs-extra");

const buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "build");
// file removal in fs-extra version
fs.removeSync(buildPath);
//path to the file
const campaignPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "contracts", "Campaign.sol");
//get a content of file
const source = fs.readFileSync(campaignPath, "utf8");
// output from the compiler
const output = solc.compile(source, 1).contracts;

for (let contract in output) {
  fs.outputJsonSync(
    path.resolve(buildPath, contract + ".json"),
    output[contract]
  );
}
```

Comment: What are you running it in?  Remix, truffle, your own self made compiler?!

What about the file Campaign.json, does it exist?  Did you accidentally tell your compiler to compile Campaign.json instead of Campaign.sol?

Without all the information we can't effectively help you.

Comment: I ran it in Remix at first, then in Atom. For better visualization:  my kickstart project contains ethereum and node_modules folders. Ethereum holds build and contracts ones accordingly. I have Campaign.json  inside the build folder of the project. (C:\kickstart\ethereum\build\Campaign.json).                                     
 I also have a Campaign.sol inside the  contracts folder (C:\kickstart\ethereum\contracts\Campaign.sol).                                          Getting this error while running node compile.js

Comment: Ok, we're getting closer to being able to answer the question.  Just to help you in the future, you didn't answer the most important of my questions.  What are you running it in?

Saying you ran it in Remix is a good answer.  But then you say you ran it in Atom yet Atom is an editor not a solidity compiler.  If I had to guess from your description about `node compile.js` it seems you are following the process described here: https://medium.com/coinmonks/how-to-compile-a-solidity-smart-contract-using-node-js-51ea7c6bf440

If you're following different instructions I need to know.

Comment: Sorry for being not clear about the compiler. I am following Ethereum and Solidty: The Complete Developer`s guide by Stephen Grider. https://www.udemy.com/ethereum-and-solidity-the-complete-developers-guide/

Comment: No need to apologize, I'm just happy we're getting closer to an answer.  Unfortunately I've never used Udemy and I can't get access to the course material.  Is there a teacher of some sort you can reach out to for the course in order to ask this question?

If not, my next question is what the purpose of Campain.json is?  Personally, I only use Remix for my solidity compiling needs and only .sol files are used, no .json.  Does the JSON file define dependencies or something?

Comment: Problem solved, please see below. Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 3):

Answering your question: Campain.json is located in the build folder and contains the output for all instances of Campaign contract.

I was able to fix the error by doing the following steps:

- Completely deleting node_modules folder in the project
- Running npm cache clean --force  command
- Running npm install

Please find the link to the project below:
https://github.com/StephenGrider/EthereumCasts

Comment: Happy to see the problem was resolved.  If you don't mind, I saw you got a -1 vote (I upped to counteract it ;) ) and this was most likely due to the lack of detail in your answer.  If you could properly format your numbers (there should be a button in the editor), and also add any information you could provide (think about the questions I asked) that'd be awesome.  **Remember** that your question and its answer aren't just for you, but for those in the future with your same problem.  When you ask or answer a question (especially a self answer) make sure you keep the future developers in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I ran across the same issue. The problem is that Windows is not happy with having special characters in the filename, in this case the colon ":" character.

As such remove the colon when you're outputting the result as follows:

```
for (let contract in output) {
  fs.outputJSONSync(
    path.resolve(buildPath, contract.replace(':', '') + ".json"),
    output[contract]
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure that your compile.js file is correctly configured add "**console.log(solc.compile(source, 1));**" before the for loop and check the output.

About this issue, you can replace:
**path.resolve(buildPath, contract + '.json')**,
with
**path.resolve(buildPath, contract.replace(':', '') + '.json')**,

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

If you have changed the filename, you need to migrate it.

```sh
npx truffle migrate --reset --compile-all
```

I had the same issue and that worked for me.